# Changing web service configuration after publishing to iis

Tags: wcf, iis, service

It might be a very silly and obvious question, I am still going to ask it anyway. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have a web service, the `web.config` before publishing was pointing to my machine and database on my machine. After publishing the service works. No problems.

When my colleague published the service without changing the `web.config` (still pointing to my machine and database on my machine) it didn't work as expected. He went to virtual directory, changed the `web.config` to point to his machine, changed the database to point to the correct database and retried. The service is still pointing to my machine.

My question is, is there any way we can edit the `web.config` after publishing to IIS and the service will use the new `web.config` changes straight away? If you need any more information please feel free to ask.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you change connection string in a web.config file changes should reflect immediately you save. Some people after changing recycle application pool. You can right click on the virtual folder on I is and open file location "Just to be sure the right web.config was edited".